# Issue with getting started with Arduino mega

Tags: arduino, atmel, avrdude

I've just got my first brand new `Arduino mega 2560` board. I've downloaded `Arduino 1.0.1` software.

When I first plugged in the board, it failed to detect the device. So I opened device manager and pointed  to the `"...\arduino-1.0.1\drivers"` folder to update the driver for the unidentified `Arduino Mega 2560`  device.

Now comes my first problem; `(O/S is window 7 32bit)`

```
Following warning came.
```

[image]

```
I chose to install anyway. Is that wrong??
```

However driver is successfully installed.

Then I opened `Arduino 1.0.1` software (what should i call it, IDE?) and opened the blink example. And tried to upload it to the board. I didn't change any settings. Kept the default settings, which are;

```
Board       = Arduino Mega 2560 or Mega ADK  
Serial Port = COM3
```

Upload failed giving following error,

```
Binary sketch size: 1,632 bytes (of a 258,048 byte maximum)
avrdude: stk500v2_command(): unknown status 0xc8
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude: stk500v2_command(): unknown status 0x01
avrdude: stk500v2_disable(): failed to leave programming mode
```

How can I get over with this? I don't have any prior experience on Arduino. Can't figure out what to do now.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me to overcome this issue. If the details I provided are not enough, please ask. Hope someone will come to help soon..

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?action=print;num=1287724404 very similar if not identical problem described with some suggestions

Comment: @Roman Saveljev thanks for quick rep. I'll try that..

Comment: Thanks @RomanSaveljev I followed your link. It gave me an idea so I checked my COM port settings. There was the problem. Default COM was wrong. When I selected correct one, problem solved!!! many thanks.

Comment: @RomanSaveljev Please put the above comment as an answer so that I can accept it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same problem with possible solution is described here:

http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?action=print;num=1287724404

Comment: Thanks. It was that simple, I should have checked before. But I assumed something worse..